# Problem with the template of a view

Tags: views

I created a template to customize labels views. But the fields are not displayed between labels.

Here are the views-view-field--sitemap--views-data-export--field-image.tpl.php :

```
<?php

$fields["field_image"]->content = '<image:loc>' . $field->original_value . '</image:loc>' . '<image:title>' . $row->field_field_image[0]['rendered']['#item']["alt"] . '</image:title>';

echo $fields["field_image"]->content;
```

and here are the views-data-export-xml-header--sitemap.tpl.php :

```
<?php print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">'; 
?>
```

and the result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">  <url>
    <loc>http://www.s1biose.com/boutique/produit/savon-d-alep-artisanal-bio-pure-olive</loc>
    <image:image>&lt;image:loc&gt;http://www.s1biose.com/sites/default/files/image/boutique/savon-d-alep-artisanal-bio-pure-olive-photo-1.jpg&lt;/image:loc&gt;</image:image>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.s1biose.com/boutique/produit/savon-d-alep-artisanal-bio-5-de-laurier</loc>
</urlset>
```

The result should be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example-1.com/sample.html</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example-1.com/image_1.jpg</image:loc>
      <image:title>title image 1</image:title>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example-1.com/image_2.jpg</image:loc>
      <image:title>title image 2</image:title>
    </image:image>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://example-2.com/sample.html</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example-2.com/image_1.jpg</image:loc>
      <image:title>title image 1</image:title>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example-2.com/image_2.jpg</image:loc>
      <image:title>title image 2</image:title>
    </image:image>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Is the template even used? Tried flushing caches?

Comment: try changing your first line to `$fields["field_image"]->content = '<image:loc>' . $row->field_field_image[0]['rendered']['#item']["uri"] . '</image:loc>' . '<image:title>' . $row->field_field_image[0]['rendered']['#item']["alt"] . '</image:title>';`

Comment: @No Sssweat :-) thank you it works but it displays 1 image instead of 3. There is also a problem with the url because it starts with "public: //" instead of "http: //"

Comment: `instead of three` **[three ???](https://www.google.ca/search?q=three&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB9MX3q_LMAhUOPlIKHXZvBw4Q_AUIBygB&biw=1280&bih=637)**

Comment: @No Sssweat yes

Comment: @Mathieu are you using unlimited values for your image field? or do the other 2 images belong to another node?

Comment: @No Sssweat all images belong to the same node, multiple parameter fields values is set to 4. I've updated the question

Comment: @No Sssweat you know how I can view the full URL of the image? I've updated the question with the results that it should give.

Comment: @Mathieu updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you know how I can view the full URL of the image?

I found it, replace your 1st line with:

```
$fields["field_image"]->content = '<image:loc>' . $field->original_value . '</image:loc>' . '<image:title>' . $row->field_field_image[0]['rendered']['#item']["alt"] . '</image:title>';
```

> thank you it works but it displays 1 image instead of 3

**In views click on your image field**, click on *MULTIPLE FIELD SETTINGS* **uncheck** display all values in the same row.

[image]

Comment: super thank you to the url complête it works. But for the image, you need the image belonging to the same node are grouped together. As in the last catch of the question.

Comment: Google Search Console does not recognize the tags
 image:loc and image:title :(

Comment: this is what it shows, just with the tag <image:loc>
 http://www.s1biose.com/sitemap-produit.xml

Comment: I found this https://www.drupal.org/node/2061697